# Virtual Machine UEFI can't type “\”

Tags: operating-systems, uefi, steam-os

I am trying to install SteamOS in Oracle VirtualBox. I know how to do it but in the UEFI, it won't let me type "\" it lets me type any other character but not this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to type any possible national characters? I'm not familiar with the UK keyboard layout, but you may want to try e.g. `£`. I'm betting the keyboard scan codes are being interpreted according to a US keyboard layout because nothing else has been loaded at that point.

Comment: If I type "£" on my keyboard it comes types "#".

Comment: Let me guess, `£` on a UK keyboard is Shift+3?

Comment: Yes, I have sorted it now. The "#" key types the "\" key in the VM. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, we've got it. Let me type up a proper answer, too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is because in the UEFI firmware setup, no specific keyboard layout has been loaded.** So it falls back to a firmware default, which almost certainly happens to be a US keyboard layout.

The computer doesn't really know what's printed on the various key caps on the keyboard. **What it does know,** is how to map *keyboard scan codes* to character numbers (normally in ASCII), which *in turn* it knows how to display as glyphs on the screen.

**What you are seeing is an effect of this indirection.**

There is a <kbd>\</kbd> key somewhere on your keyboard while you're in the UEFI setup (and it turns out it's the same key that is normally used for <kbd>#</kbd> on the UK keyboard layout, as we found out in the comments), and you'll just have to do a bit of experimentation to find it. You should be able to find any key that exists on a US keyboard layout, although the physical location of the key that produces that glyph may be somewhat non-obvious.

You'll see the same effect if you set your operating system to use a US keyboard layout.